# Pass array by reference to Laravel Event Listener

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I have an array in Laravel applications that I would like to modify in Laravel listener. PHP by default passes an array by value however, the way Laravel events and its listeners work I am unable to modify the original variable. Is there a better way than what I am doing below?

The Model where the event is fired from.

Model: **Event.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Package\Models

use Vendor\Package\Events\PageNodeArrayAfter;
use Event;

class Page
{
   public function toArray()
   {
      $data = []; 

      // do something with the data. 

      Event::fire(new PageNodeToArrayAfter($data))

      // The data should be modified by a listener when I use it here.
   }
}
```

Event: **PageNodeToArrayAfter.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Package\Events;

class PageNodeToArrayAfter
{
    /**
     * Props to be sent to the view
     * @var array $data
     */
    protected $data = [];

    /**
     * @param array $data
     * 
     */
    public function __construct(array &$data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function getData()
    {
        return $this->data;
    }
}
```

Listener: **FlashMessagesListner.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Package\Listeners;

class FlashMessagesListner
{
    protected $data = [];

    public function handle(PageNodeToArrayAfter $event)
    {
       $this->data = $event->getData();
       // The problem here is the $data is no logner a reference here. 
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your use-case? Why do you need to achieve this? Your main thread (the one that executes the event) will keep running even though your listener may have not been completed.

Comment: I am converting some XML nodes to an array and during the process, I wanted to append some custom data such as validation messages via independent listeners.

Comment: I see. You need to customize your XML data, so why make use of listener? event/listeners are used to notify other parts of your app (or an external API) about something, but in your case you want to make operations over the same data that you will keep touching. I undertand that you want to decouple your logic to avoid recharging your function with a lot of code. So you could extract that logic to a function, a trait or another class that will return the updated XML file.

Comment: I agree with @HCK that the observer pattern is a wrong approach here because your conversion might finish before the listeners are done with their job.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and I hear your point, to add more to my aforementioned use case -  this is how the data will flow in my application:  Request->Controller->XML Node Parser->Data->View->Response (for brevity I skipped some of the steps).  The data passed to the view may need to be modified for various reasons  and I don't think a trait could solve a problem here. In this scenario I want to include laravel validation messages, and in some other scenarion I may need to add some other data. 
The view here is not blade I am using a microservice for that.

Comment: Events and listeners are used to decouple processes. If you only need to flash some validation messages into the session, I don't see how you'd need the array to be passed by reference. If the logic of your listeners is essential for the process of another part of the application, a listener is the wrong choice anyway. Event listeners should only be used if the firing process doesn't care whether an event is used by any other process or not (_process_ in terms of _business process_, not thread). I.e. sending a welcome mail after a user registered (which is completely optional for the process).

Comment: thank you, everyone, for the suggestion and making me think of an alternate way of doing it. I think to do filter this through the Laravel Pipeline instead of the listeners. There is an interesting article which helped me understand it https://jeffochoa.me/understanding-laravel-pipelines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appreciate all the responses, feedback on the question and suggestions to look for a better way of doing it.

Now instead of using Listeners, I tried Laravel Pipeline which is a great way of passing the data through different pipes and in my case filtering it. This article has been very helpful in understanding it https://jeffochoa.me/understanding-laravel-pipelines

Here is the final version of my code and how am I using Laravel Pipeline:

Node: **Page.php**

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Package\Nodes;


class Page extends ReactPage
{
    public function toArray() : array
    {
        $data = parent::toArray();

        $pipes = [
           AppendFlashMessage::class,
           RemoveEmptyLayoutNode::class
        ];


        // Filter data through the pipelines. 
        $data = app(Pipeline::class)
            ->send($data)
            ->through($pipes)
            ->via('filter')
            ->then(function($data) {
                return $data;
        });

        return $data;
    }
}
```

Pipe: **AppendFlashMessage.php**

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Package\Pipeline;

use Closure;

class AppendFlashMessage
{

    public function filter(array $data, Closure $next) : array
    {

        // step 1: pull the errors from session.
        $errors = [
            'type' => 'error',
            'message' => 'Invalid User Name'
        ];

        $data['messages'] = $errors;
        return $next($data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation for the [array](https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) this is what it says:

> Array assignment always involves value copying. Use the reference operator to copy an array by reference.

So change your constructor to this instead:

```
// prepend the argument with the reference operator &
public function __construct(array &$data)
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. How do you modify the referenced variable in the Listener? I just updated my question and included the & operator which was intended to be there originally.

Comment: I for now just used a setter and getter to modify the variable, now I probably won't need to pass it by reference.

Comment: it answers the part where you state that by default arrays in PHP are passed by reference which are not. To me it does not make sense to use a listener and from within the listener to modify an outside variable first of all, because that process is async when you fire an event, the next line after the event is being executed even though the listener has not finished it's job.

Comment: Yes, that what I am thinking now. I probably don't need to pass the variable to the listener by reference and hence my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the reference sign in the event's constructor:

```
/**
 * @param array $data
 * 
 */
public function __construct(array &$data)
{
    $this->data = &$data;
                  ^
}
```

While this provides an accurate answer to the question, I do not recommend using the observer pattern for this particular use case.

Also, you don't need an accessor - instead just make the `data` property public and use `$event->data` in your listener.

Answer (score 0):

The initial event that is fired is passed by reference (since it's an object). The modified $data property in that object can be accessed after listener execution.

```
  event($e = new PageNodeToArrayAfter($data));
  $data = $e->getData();
```

No need to pass anything manually by reference in event constructor or getter.